# Is it possible to exclude classes/packages when depending on a JAR?

Tags: jar, dependency-management, gradle

I need to depend on a JAR file that contains the entire JUnit 3 package, but I bundle JUnit 4 separately with my project. Hence, my test break because they are executed using the JUnit 3 runner, when they should instead be run using the JUnit 4 runner.

The question is: can I tell Gradle to not include certain classes or entire packages from a JAR when depending on it?

**UPDATE**
It worked using the suggested zipTree/copy solution:

```
task processAndroidJar(type: Copy) {
  from zipTree("$androidHome/platforms/android-8/android.jar")
  into "$buildDir/android"
  exclude "junit/**"
}

compileJava.dependsOn processAndroidJar

dependencies {
  compile files("$buildDir/android")
}
```

Works beautifully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to depend on jar file as a `ZipTree`
`ZipTree` allows you to include/exclude different paths within archive in your dependency

Comment: cool, any concrete examples? The Gradle user guide only very briefly mentions ZipTree; how would I use it to generate a modified JAR dependency?

Comment: I updated my question with the zipTree approach, but it now doesn't compile anymore. Ideas?

Comment: There is one big drawback in this approach. if you just do `compile filtere` - you will only add a bunch of *.class files to the classpath. Unfortunately, you will have to copy all these files to a separate temp dir, and add this dir to classpath.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about that, too. The odd thing is: Gradle already does that. The `println` statement I put in there reveals that the JAR is unzipped to a tmp directory within my project directory (so it's not just an in-memory deflation). Also, the `filtered` object is a `FileTree`, so why does it still not work? Passing a tree of class files as a dependency surely must work somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately, passing tree of class files as a dependency does not work. And I think, it must not. Here is why: files from dependency are combined into *classpath*, passed to underlying `javac` execution. Adding bunch of individual *.class files to compiler's classpath wont do the trick. You should, instead, add the root directory of the unpacked files.

Comment: There are 2 more problems: you can not get the root of unpacked tmp directory from `ZipFileTree` instance and `ZipFileTree` is *lazy*. Copying zipTree content to new directory and adding it to dependecy could solve the question. Sorry I can not check it now myself.

Comment: Cheers, I will give it a shot tomorrow at work. Thanks again for your time.